# Number of building block structures following a set of rules

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, young-tableaux

If we have an *n* amount of building blocks, and we are tasked with making, what I have found out are 'Young Tableau' like structures (though I am unsure if they are exactly the same), how many can we make out of the *n* amount of blocks.
The trick is that for every two consecutive columns the next one is at most as high as the previous one (**i** is at least as high as **i + 1**.) and the same applies to rows.
So for example *3* blocks can be built like this:

```
1        
2     1
3     2 3     1 2 3
```

So out of 3 blocks, we can make 3 structures following these rules. Then 5 out of 4 blocks, 7 out of 5, 10 out of 6. My problem is that I am unable to generalize this into a working equation, so for example how many structures we can make out of 15 blocks, is absolutely beyond me.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: in @saulspatz 's comment link, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts for a simple recursive formula that allows for spreadsheet calculation.